# Design suggestion for a page with two links

Tags: website-design, gui-design, hyperlinks, redirect, white-space

I'm trying to figure out the best way to present just two links on a page.  This page appears after login and redirects users to the selected page.
Do you have any suggestion for this type of page?

[image]

Comment: Could you combine this with the login page ? Ie enter username; enter password; press appropriate button ?

Comment: I agree with @PhillipW - integrate the choice into the login page if that makes sense. Alternatively, once they've navigated to one page or the other, can the user easily jump between them? If so, is there a sensible default that everyone could be sent to?

Answer (score 3):

In general, I like PhillipW's idea of providing two buttons on the log-in page, but due to the name "Dashboard", I would recommend always taking users there first as a landing page (that's what's communicated in my mind by a "Dashboard"). There can be a large, easy to find button that takes them to the Report System from the Dashboard. Also, there could be a user preference or setting for advanced users that customizes what their default page is if they would prefer automatically going to Report System instead Dashboard.

Comment: +1, Agree 100%. The 2 button page has 100% of users click an extra link, with your suggestion that's at least 50% less. Also think about new users who don't know what to choose, just take them to the most likely place.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want this page works like this, you only make them more obvious to the users such and more appealing, maybe you could add some icons and a small description.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQBZd4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a background image that makes the buttons more visible or you can try something more creative like split the screen into two sections, each with a screenshot of the page mentioned in the buttons (dashboard/ report system) and the correspondent button.

This simple page, with a lot of white space, reminds me of an empty state and I think you could find inspiration on [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/empty-states.html#empty-states-displaying-empty-states):

> Displaying empty states
>
> The most basic empty state displays a non-interactive image and a text
>   tagline.
>
> Use an image that:
>
> Is subtle and neutral with respect to the background Conveys the
>   purpose and potential of the app in a lively way, such as your app's
>   icon Include a tagline that:
>
> Has a positive tone Is consistent with your brand Conveys the purpose
>   of the app without appearing to be actionable

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine the action if there's a single action once logged in?

[image: Login with action]

Answer (score 0):

With this small amount of information I would suggest to take the user to the dashboard first, as J. Dimeo did.

You could try to find out, what your users need. Think about the task users want to achieve with your application. Is the dashboard clearly used more often or the report system? Maybe you could create a diagram like [this](http://userfocus.co.uk/images/tomtom.png) (source: http://userfocus.co.uk/articles/prioritising-functions.html) and find it out.

As seen in the comment from Martyn, if thought about new users, the way to the dashboard would be most likely the best. But what do advanced users or power users want?

Maybe You can ask your users, what they want or test it with a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

From a Information Architecture point of view would it not make sense to have Dashboard shown first on login and then a "Switch to Reporting" button prominently on the page?

Answer (score -2):

Blue generally means something that's official about now, green is something we think of as go. And since I'm assuming reports is the purpose of this... and due to our trained use of options and values of relevance to current knowledge being top right, and our expectation of identification, furtherance and purpose being bottom right, these two buttons should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any sources on those color correlations?